# How can I draw a graph with three variables on the y axis in R?

Tags: r, axis, sharing

I have a data set with a nominale variable "count session" and three other quantitatives variables including wildlife counts from three different methods. 
I would like to plot my group sizes from the different methods (y-axis) against the count session. 
I am a beginner with R. Do you know any function that would allow me to do that?

@siva974: Data belongs in the question *not* in comments:

```
 COUNT 
SESSION MEANVISUAL MEANOVERLAP MEANWIDEANGLE 
1 290 286 NA 
2 137 132 120 
3 289 280 289 
4 310 287 250 
5 280 286 260 
6 139 142 144
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. What have you tried?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally in base graphics you would create an initial plot using one variable on the y-axis (but leaving room to add the others), then use the function `points` or `lines` to add the additional variables to the existing plot.

There are alternative ways to plot such as ggplot2 or lattice graphics, sometimes it is easier to make complicated plots using these tools (and sometimes it is harder).

If you can give more detail on your data and what you would like the plot to look like then we can give more help.

A first try would be something like:

```
with(COUNT, plot(SESSION, MEANVISUAL, type='b', 
  ylim=range(MEANVISUAL,MEANOVERLAP,MEANWIDEANGLE)))
with(COUNT, lines(SESSION, MEANOVERLAP, type='b', col='blue', pch=2))
with(COUNT, lines(SESSION, MEANWIDEANGLE, type='b', col='green', pch=3))
```

Or possibly use the `matplot` function:

```
matplot( COUNT$SESSION, COUNT[ , 2:4], type='b' )
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! I must say I do not really understand how I can use `points` to add another variable...
I am counting a species with three different methods : visual count with binoculars, image-processing count using wide angle photographs and image-processing count using overlapping photographs. Thus, for each of my count session I have 3 counts for the same group.
Ideally I would like to have a plot with my count session as the x-axis and my three methods on the y-axis, using different symbols for each method.

Comment: @siva974, can you provide a sample dataset?  either the real data, or the same structure with made up numbers.

Comment: Sure, 

COUNT SESSION       MEANVISUAL       MEANOVERLAP        MEANWIDEANGLE
      1                 290              286                 NA
      2                 137              132                 120
      3                 289              280                 289
      4                 310              287                 250
      5                 280              286                 260
      6                 139              142                 144

Comment: @siva974, I have added some examples of possible code to use (there are other ways you could code this, but this could get you started).

Comment: Thank you so much! the `matplot` function is perfect!